# elastic search java client mapper_parsing_exception failed to parse field [timeStamp] of type [long] in document?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am accessing elastic search by java client. i was inserting date as timestamp in long. but now want to store in like **2019-12-02T12:08:54.053Z**. i am getting bellow error.

```
"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse field [timeStamp] of type [long] in document
```

however i did not set any kind of data type for time stamp field, then why i am getting such kind of exception.
is there any chance because of old record i am getting above error.

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of elasticsearch called dynamic mappings, when elasticsearch see a new field, it'll try to deduce the type of this field according to certain rules that you can find in their documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html

Your field timeStamp is mapped as long, and when you try to insert a date in this field it cause an exception.

You have to re-index all of your data or save the timeStamp as long

Comment: thanks for the answer can you please help me. how can i re-index in java

Comment: depending on the version of your elasticsearch, check out this url https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html but this time define the mappings of your field in your new index, for example configure your field timeStamp to be date and specify all your acceptable data formats.